# Alternative to using global parameters in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a better way to implement a code like this without using global parameters?
I was taught that global parameters generally isnt a good thing in python.
What do you guys think? do you think global parameters are okay?

This is the code

```
import Tkinter as tk


def main():    
    global root

    root = tk.Tk()   # parent window


    message = tk.Label(root, text = "Hello World") 
    message.pack() 

    buttton = tk.Button(root, text="exit", command = buttonPushed) 
    button.pack()

    tk.mainloop()  


def buttonPushed():
    global root
    root.destroy()

main()
```

on the line where I create the button, if instead I write something like this;

```
buttton = tk.Button(root, text="exit", command = buttonPushed(root)) 
button.pack()


def buttonPushed(root):
    root.destroy()
```

the program will not work as required.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `buttonPushed` function is unnecessary because you can assign the button's `command` parameter to the `root.destroy` function directly:

```
button = tk.Button(root, text="exit", command=root.destroy)
```

Thus, your code becomes just this<sup>1</sup>:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def main():    

    root = tk.Tk()

    message = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World") 
    message.pack() 

    button = tk.Button(root, text="exit", command=root.destroy) 
    button.pack()

    tk.mainloop()  

main()
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Note:  I also removed the `global root` line at the top of `main` because it is unnecessary.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can write it using [classes](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html) but as iCodez says, that button is kind of unnecessary right now.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class interface(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.root = root
        message = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Hello World") 
        button = tk.Button(self.root, text="exit", command = self.buttonPushed) 

        message.pack()
        button.pack()

    def buttonPushed(self):
        self.root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
inter = interface(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Class is a wise advice to maintain state without relying on global state. But your implementation has a few flaws: interface constructor does not call Frame constructor, and to access root you should either use [iCodez](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23394942/) advice to use root.destroy, store root in interface attribute or rely on inherited `self.parent` in `buttonPushed`.